# Why did we add a dot in multiplication in order to run the program?

Tags: c, math, operators

I'm writing a program that calculates the roots of the quadratic equation. When I first wrote the code I didn't type a dot after 4 and 2 in the x equation and it didn't work! So what does that dot represent here and when should I use it?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<math.h>

int main()
{
   int a, b, c;
   double x;
   scanf("%d %d %d", &a, &b, &c); 

   x = (-b + sqrt(b*b-4.*a*c) ) / (2.*a);

   printf("%lf", x);
   getch();

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Probably `a`, `b`, and `c` should also be of type `double`.

Comment: No it was stated in the problems that it should all be integers! The explanation is in Mitch Wheat's answer below.

Comment: They may be integers in the real problem but you are still performing floating point arithmetic when they get used in the quadratic solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`4.` is `4.0`

The decimal point makes it a float literal rather than an integer literal.

The more important literal is `2.` as without it you would get integer division (and in most cases, the wrong result).

Answer (score 1):

Integer literals are interpreted by the compiler as integers, which means that operations such as division are performed in their integer form if all operands are integers. The decimal point makes it a floating literal, which means that the compiler will use the floating form of the operations instead.